# In tcp connection termination

Tags: tcp

If it doesn't close in both directions, will it never close - regardless of expiration timers? - It can half-close but can the tcp connection terminate if only one initiates the close()?

In other words: 
In TCP connection termination - can you close the connection fully when only the client initiates a close but the server does not.
Or can a tcp connection be closed by both ways independently?

Comment: Please elaborate, it is unclear to me.

Comment: You are using a lot of terms that are unclear in context. For example, when you say "close in both directions", do you mean each side calls `close`? Or do you mean each of the two directions of the TCP connection (it is a bidirectional stream, right?) get shutdown? When you say "half-close", do you mean one side has closed both directions of the stream? Or do you mean one side has closed its send direction but the receive direction is still open? Your question is filled with vague terms that make it impossible to understand what you're asking.

Comment: And, more vague terms, does "initiates a close" mean that it calls `close`? Or does it mean that it calls `shutdown` to indicate that it won't send anymore? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each peer can close the TCP connection independent from the other and the peer will simply get an EOF (e.g no more bytes) when it tries to read from the peer or get an ECONNRESET or EPIPE if it tries to write to a connection which was closed by the peer, but only if the socket is aware that the peer does not want to receive more data, see below.

Closing a connection consists actually of two parts:

- Application will not send any more data: `shutdown(sock,SHUT_WR)`. In this case the kernel will send a FIN to the peer so signalize that no more data will follow. Reading from the peer will return EOF.
- Application does not want to receive more data: `shutdown(sock,SHUT_RD)`. In this case no information will be send to the peer initially, but if data get received from the peer they will be rejected with RST.

A call of `close()` is thus equivalent of shutting down both sides of the connection at the same time (`SHUT_RDWR`).